# Duplicate content and international sites clarification

Tags: seo, search-engine, multilingual, duplicate-content

Something is not clear, here is my case:
i want to have have the same content for us and uk people,
could i safely avoid duplicate content with thoses url:
www.example.us/info.html (hosted on us server)
www.example.co.uk/info.html  (hosted on uk server)

**from google :**
Websites that provide content for different regions and in different languages sometimes create content that is the same or similar but available on different URLs. This is generally not a problem as long as the content is for different users in different countries. While we strongly recommend that you provide unique content for each different group of users, we understand that this might not always be possible. There is generally no need to "hide" the duplicates by disallowing crawling in a robots.txt file or by using a "noindex" robots meta tag. However, if you're providing the same content to the same users on different URLs (for instance, if both example.de/ and example.com/de/ show German language content for users in Germany), you should pick a preferred version and redirect (or use the rel=canonical link element) appropriately. In addition, you should follow the guidelines on rel-alternate-hreflang to make sure that the correct language or regional URL is served to searchers.

Seems not clear for me, what do you think about my case ?!

flau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for [hreflang](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/internationalization-multi-language-seo-checklist.html). When implemented properly, you will avoid all duplicate content issues.

Answer (score 0):

> if you're providing the same content to the same users on different URLs (for instance, if both example.de/ and example.com/de/ show German language content for users in Germany), you should pick a preferred version and redirect (or use the rel=canonical link element) appropriately. In addition, you should follow the guidelines on rel-alternate-hreflang to make sure that the correct language or regional URL is served to searchers

That covers your scenario:

- Choose one as your preferred URL for the US and make it redirect (or use canonical), and
- Follow hreflang guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en